# Fill an array with ascending sequence of numbers with conditions

Tags: javascript

How do I fill an array with an ascending sequence of numbers with these conditions  :

- the first element in the array is `let a = 0;`
- the sum of array elements is equal to `var sum = 10;`
- the length of the array should be `var length = 10;`

here is the code I've created :

```js
    var length = 10;
    var array = []; 
    var sum = 10; // the sum of all elements in the array should be equal to this
        
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        let a = 0; // the very first element of array
        // Math equations
        let last = (sum - (length / 2 * a)) * 2 / length
        let dd = (last - a) / (length - 1)
    
        sume = (dd * (i));
        array.push(sume);
    
    }

    // check to see if array elemements sum is equal to "var sum = 10"
    let reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
    let sumArray = array.reduce(reducer);
    console.log("sumArray: " + sumArray)
    
    console.log(array) // results
```

But the problem is instead of having round numbers (it still matches all my conditions) like this :

`[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]`

But I get these results:

`[0, 0.2222222222222222, 0.4444444444444444, 0.6666666666666666, 0.8888888888888888, 1.1111111111111112, 1.3333333333333333, 1.5555555555555554, 1.7777777777777777, 2]`

Note: I calculated the last item here : `let last = (sum - length / 2 * a) * 2 / length` and the first one is always 0...

Comment: can't you fill array with ones and set the first element to 0 and last to 2? `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]`

Comment: No; all variables are not fixed ones.  for instance, I may change those to `var length = 20;
    var array = []; 
    var sum = 50;`

Comment: No, last element is `let last = (sum - length / 2 * a) * 2 / length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum / length` is the middle value in the array
`sum / length * 2` is the last value in the array
`/ (length - 1) * index` is to get percentage of the last value based on the index
and `+ .5 | 0` is short for `Math.round`

```js
const sequence = (L, S) => [...Array(L)].map((v, i) => S / L * 2 / (L - 1) * i + .5 | 0)

const test = (L, S, arr = sequence(L, S)) => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b) + ' : ' + arr

console.log( test(10, 10) )
console.log( test(10, 30) )
console.log( test(20, 50) )
```

Comment: I'm curious to know how did you write this... is there any step by step logic or you just wrote and debugged?

Comment: @SaraRee there was some logic as the first item is zero times the average, the last item is two times the average, and that the index of each item in the array should be part of the formula. There was also some trial and error. Not sure if you noticed, but my answer is almost the same as Nina's second code snipped.

Answer (score 2):

You could round the values.

```
sume = Math.round(dd * i);
```

```js
    var length = 10;
    var array = []; 
    var sum = 10; // the sum of all elements in the array should be equal to this
        
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        let a = 0; // the very first element of array
        // Math equations
        let last = (sum - length / 2 * a) * 2 / length
        let dd = (last - a) / (length - 1)
    
        sume = Math.round(dd * i);
        array.push(sume);
    
    }

    // check to see if array elemements sum is equal to "var sum = 10"
    let reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
    let sumArray = array.reduce(reducer);
    console.log("sumArray: " + sumArray)
    
    console.log(array) // results
```

A shorter approach with rounding (it might nott work for all cases).

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b;

function disperse(length, sum) {
    var min = 0,
        max = sum * 2 / length,
        array = Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => Math.round(min + i * max / (length - 1)));
    return [array.reduce(add), array.join(', ')];
}

console.log(disperse(10, 10));
console.log(disperse(10, 30));
console.log(disperse(20, 50));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: One question: How you can be sure that the sum will be intact

Comment: to have the same sum, you need to give some constrainst, like starting value, if you like to have integer values, how many of one value and a geraestest value. a soulution would rely on that.

Comment: I calculated the last item here : `let last = (sum - length / 2 * a) * 2 / length` and the first one is always 0...

Comment: Thanks... But try this: `console.log(disperse(10, 30));` the sum changes to 33!

Comment: what would the wanted result for this parameters?

Comment: I have created another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917042/different-results-while-using-same-function

Comment: The code works fine even with these parameters (10, 30) but there is a bug on my code...:(